# Q: Construct a basis $β$ for $V$ such that $[T]_{\beta}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}0_{2x2} & X\\\ 0_{2x2} & 0_{2x2}\end{pmatrix}$ for some $X \in M_{2x2}(C)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I've done similar questions regarding finding a basis for vector spaces, however this particular question I'm having difficulty to knowing even where to begin.
Any guidance on where to start would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Question:
Consider the vector space $V = C^{2}$ with scalar multiplication over the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, and let $T : V \rightarrow V$ be the linear operator defined by $$T(\begin{bmatrix}z_{1} \\\ z_{2} \end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & i \\\ i & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}z_{1} \\\ z_{2} \end{bmatrix}$$

Construct a basis $β$ for $V$ such that $[T]_{\beta}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}0_{2x2} & X\\\ 0_{2x2} & 0_{2x2}\end{pmatrix}$ for some $X \in M_{2x2}(C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\beta=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$, then, since $[T]_\beta=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0_{2\times2}&X\\0_{2\times2}&0_{2\times2}\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, $T(v_1)=T(v_2)=0$. Besides, if $z_1=i$ and $z_2=1$, you have $T\left(\left[\begin{smallmatrix}z_1\\z_2\end{smallmatrix}\right]\right)=0$. So, take $v_1(i,1)$. For the same reason, you can take $v_2=(-1,i)$. Now, find $v_3$ and $v_4$ such that both $T(v_3)$ and $T(v_4)$ are linear combinations of $v_1$ and $v_2$.